# For each and TypeOf doesn't work (don't charge any text on RichTextBox) on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, foreach, styles, controls, typeof

Well I want to make a global style for all the RichTextBox of my form:

With:

```
Public Class RichTextLabel

Public Shared Sub AddTextWithFont(ByVal sText As String, ByVal oFont As Font)

    For Each cControl In frmMain.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is RichTextBox) Then
            Dim index As Integer
            index = cControl.TextLength
            cControl.AppendText(sText)
            cControl.SelectionStart = index
            cControl.SelectionLength = cControl.TextLength - index
            cControl.SelectionFont = oFont
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Sub AddTextWithColor(ByVal sText As String, ByVal oColor As Color)

    For Each cControl In frmMain.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is RichTextBox) Then
            Dim index As Integer
            index = cControl.TextLength
            cControl.AppendText(sText)
            cControl.SelectionStart = index
            cControl.SelectionLength = cControl.TextLength - index
            cControl.SelectionColor = oColor
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

And:

```
    RichTextLabel.AddTextWithFont("Estado del Spammer: ", New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold))
    RichTextLabel.AddTextWithColor(state, Color.Red)
```

I don't know what its wrong... :(

Comment: Doesn't work doesn't tell us anything.  What do you mean by doesn't work - does it not do anything, does it throw an exception, etc.

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong? What happens when you try to run the code, and how does that differ from what you expect? Do you get any error message?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, all the text was in blank.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work :

```
    For Each cControl As Control In frmMain.Controls
        If (TypeOf cControl Is RichTextBox) Then
            Dim rtb As RichTextBox = CType(cControl, RichTextBox)

            Dim index As Integer
            index = rtb.TextLength
            rtb.AppendText(sText)
            rtb.SelectionStart = index
            rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.TextLength - index
            rtb.SelectionFont = oFont
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve it:

```
Public Class RichTextLabel

Public Shared Sub AddTextWithFont(ByVal sText As String, ByVal oFont As Font, ByVal rtb As RichTextBox)

    Dim index As Integer
    index = rtb.TextLength
    rtb.AppendText(sText)
    rtb.SelectionStart = index
    rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.TextLength - index
    rtb.SelectionFont = oFont

End Sub

Public Shared Sub AddTextWithColor(ByVal sText As String, ByVal oColor As Color, ByVal rtb As RichTextBox)

    Dim index As Integer
    index = rtb.TextLength
    rtb.AppendText(sText)
    rtb.SelectionStart = index
    rtb.SelectionLength = rtb.TextLength - index
    rtb.SelectionColor = oColor
End Sub
End Class
```

And:

```
RichTextLabel.AddTextWithFont("Estado del Spammer: ", New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Bold), RichTextBox1)
RichTextLabel.AddTextWithColor(state, Color.Red, RichTextBox1)
```